# Fixed Effects Regression, weird Residual Plots

Tags: r, regression, residuals, skewness

I am running regressions analysing drought impacts on electricity generation based on fueltype of the generator. I transform the outcome variable (daily_generation) using an inverse hyperbolic sine transformation to account for meaningful zero values.

The distribution of daily_quantity and ihs(daily_quantity) can be seen in the following two plots:

[image: Without IHS]
[image: With IHS]

When estimating my regressions:

```
reg5 <- feols(ihs(daily_quantity) ~ drought_index : resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + exports| name + date, data=nozeros)
reg6 <- feols(ihs(daily_quantity) ~ drought_index : resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + exports| name + date, data=panel)

reg5_a <- feols(daily_quantity ~ drought_index : resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + exports| name + date, data=nozeros)
reg6_a <- feols(daily_quantity ~ drought_index : resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + exports| name + date, data=panel)
```

I receive the following residual plots:
Not only does it seem like there is major heteroskedasticity, but there are also patterns (the straight diagonal lines). When looking at the density plots, I am assuming that they are driven by the zeros present in the data, which is why i excluded all zeros in regressions 5 and 5_a. While less pronounced in the IHS transformed plot, the patterns still exist.

Does this make my analysis invalid? How may I address these problems?

[image]

Comment: Your transform creates the problem.  Consider dealing with the zero values in a different way.  BTW, it looks like you haven't included "power plant type" as an explanatory variable, even though your density plots indicate it is perhaps the most important variable.  Why did you omit it?